# Sitecore & Lucene search auto-complete using NGram

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore8

I'm trying to setup autocomplete for content search using Ngram.
Here is my lucene index:

```
<autocompleteSearchConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
      <indexAllFields>false</indexAllFields>
      <initializeOnAdd>true</initializeOnAdd>
      <analyzer ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/analyzer" />
      <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
          <field
            fieldName="page_title"
            storageType="YES"
            indexType="TOKENIZED"
            vectorType="NO"
            boost="1.5f"
            nullValue="NULL"
            emptyString="EMPTY"
            type="System.String"
            settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.NGramAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          </field>
        </fieldNames>
      </fieldMap>
      <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
        <field fieldName="page_title" storageType="yes">Client.Website.Code.Search.AutoCompleteTitle, Client.Website</field>
      </fields>
      <fieldReaders ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/fieldReaders"/>
      <indexFieldStorageValueFormatter ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/indexFieldStorageValueFormatter"/>
      <indexDocumentPropertyMapper ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/indexDocumentPropertyMapper"/>
      <documentBuilderType>Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneDocumentBuilder, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider</documentBuilderType>
    </autocompleteSearchConfiguration>
```

Notice that I am using the NgramAnalyzer (reference: Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers).

When I look at this index in luke, I can see that it manifests the correct data.
However, the following iQueryable doesn't retain any result.

```cs
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("INDEX NAME GOES HERE");
using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
{
var query = context.GetQueryable<AutocompleteSearchResult>().Where(i => i.PageTitle == term)
var result = query.GetResults();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use "StartsWith" instead of ==?

See [this](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/search_and_item_buckets/supporting_autocomplete_with_ngram) article.

> Sitecore provides an n-gram analyzer for Lucene.net (Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers). If you use Solr, you can set this up in the Solr Schema.xml file.
>
> You use the n-gram analyzer to create autocomplete functionality for search input. The analyzer breaks tokens up into unigrams, bigrams, trigrams, and so on. When a user types a word, the n-gram analyzer looks the word up in different positions, using the tokens that it generated.
>
> You add support for autocomplete by adding a new field to the index and mapping this field to use the n-gram analyzer instead of the default. When you run the LINQ query to query that field, use the following code:

```
using (IProviderSearchContext context = Index.CreateSearchContext())
        {
            result = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().
                .Where(i => i.Name.StartsWith(“some”))
                .Take(20)
                .ToList();
        }
```

> Sitecore provides an implementation that uses trigrams and a set of English stop words. If you have other requirements, you can build a new analyzer and change these settings.

Comment: In http://www.ehabelgindy.com/sitecore-7-solr-search-auto-complete-using-ngram/ the author is suggesting not to use .startswith().

Comment: That's for Solr.  Maybe they made == behave differently?  What happens when you use StartsWith?

Answer (score 1):

Building an auto-complete search in Sitecore using n-grams is a bit harder to achieve with Lucene than it is with Solr. There are mainly two reasons for that:

1. You need to create your own analyzer as `Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.NGramAnalyzer` is not built for auto-complete purposes.
2. You need to prevent that your search query is analyzed by the `NGramAnalyzer`. By using Lucene as your search provider, you don’t have a nice `schema.xml` where you are able to configure the indexing and querying analyzers as you want. This needs to be done manually in code.

For more information on how you build such an auto-complete search, please follow [this article](https://sitecore.namics.com/2016/12/20/adventtipp-20-sitecore-lucene-search-auto-complete-using-ngram/).